# Encode Data as ASN1 Blob

Tags: c#, cryptography, asn.1

I need to store various binary data as blob in a database. Apart from a custom format, I noticed that I may be able to use the *ASN.1* format.

Now, I could write an own *ASN* encoder, but before that I would like to ask:

Is there a *C#* library which can easily encode data to the *ASN.1* Format?

I've seen [Lev Walkin blog on *ASN.1*](http://lionet.info/asn1c/blog/) which I could obviously use through interop... but I was wondering if *.NET* already provides something handy.

I've seen the *System.Security.Cryptography* namespace, but it seems to be only for decrypting *ASN* data (more or less to get a cryptographic certificates etc.).

Comment: Did you take a look on [this free ASN encode/decode library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bercodec/)?

Comment: Interesting, thanks a lot. I would rather have used an internal .NET library then an open-source project like this, if this is my only option I will implement an encoder myself, but +1 for good suggestion

Comment: ASN.1 is a notation and set of rules that describe how to structure objects. You'll need to choose/create a specific ASN.1 *structure* that you wish to use to store your data. I.e. you can't just make something into "ASN.1 format" - you need to encode it as an ASN.1 object (either a [basic type](http://www.obj-sys.com/asn1tutorial/node10.html) or a more complex structure composed of basic types).

Comment: @Duncan, well yes, I thought that was somehow implied... please excuse me if I was not clear enough...

Comment: Be warned that many libraries simply provide for BER/DER encoding/decoding. This is not what ASN.1 in itself is about. ASN.1 is about defining the structures (as Duncan indicated). Normally you should then auto-generate the classes for your particular programming environment and use the BER/DER (or even PER) parser underneath to read in the structures. Don't spend too much time on this though, if you cannot get it to work serialize your data directly using BER/DER libraries.

Comment: @owlstead Thanks for the clarification. Actually, I'm now going to mostly just use the DER encoding/decoding. I guess I was myself not completely clear on what I want. Altogether I know know enough to continue working, thanks for all helpful comments.

Comment: @Duncan I guess I should have thought more about your comment, it does seem to nicely wrap up what I was missing.

Answer (score 2):

See the ASN.1 Tools page at ITU-T (https://www.itu.int/ITU-T/asn1/links/index.htm) for a great list of ASN.1 Tools (some free, some commercial).  I know some of the commercial tools support C#.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, haven't yet found exactly what I'm looking for but at least I know very good places to look

Answer (score 1):

Also have a look at ASN writer and reader from Microsoft

- https://github.com/dotnet/designs/blob/main/accepted/2020/asnreader/asnreader.md
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.formats.asn1?view=net-8.0

Relevant question in stackover flow - [How to use System.Formats.Asn1.AsnReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70217305/how-to-use-system-formats-asn1-asnreader)