# How to use System.Formats.Asn1.AsnReader

Tags: c#, asn.1

Since [June 2020](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/36729#issuecomment-641402700) .net has a an [ASN1 reader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.formats.asn1.asnreader?view=net-6.0) implemented. In the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.formats.asn1.asnreader?view=net-6.0) there is no example how to use it. Also a search at Google and in SO doesn't show any examples or descriptions. Where can I find some?

Comment: A good way to learn about obscure parts of the standard libraries is to simply check the tests in the source code. While they might be small and isolated they will often give you a good idea about how to use the thing that is tested. For the ASN1 stuff the tests are here: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/tree/main/src/libraries/System.Formats.Asn1/tests

Comment: "How can I use this library?" is too broad of a question for Stack Overflow. The place to start understanding is with the documentation, or by using a search engine to find a tutorial. Please read [ask] and come to Stack Overflow when you have a *specific* question, ideally backed up by a clear problem description with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I rephrased the question to be more _specific_. But in general the question remains: where is the documentation for this class?

Comment: I don't understand. As far as I can tell, you have already linked the documentation. There's a big section labelled "Methods" that shows all the things you can do with the class, and what they're used for. Proceeding from there is a question of knowing C# syntax and understanding what ASN1 actually is (and if you don't, why are you looking for this class in the first place?).

Comment: Well, there is a reason, why Microsoft typically has examples in its documentation: to make the use of a class / library easier. And this is missing for this class. There is nothing. Even the pull request is labeled with "new-api-needs-documentation". And that's why I opened this question.

Answer (score 7):

I found the [design document](https://github.com/dotnet/designs/blob/ec974c0b7d87d984f498651af2a3e157ba579f01/accepted/2020/asnreader/asnreader.md) at Microsoft (very well hidden) with some examples. And kudos to [Karl-Johan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/547640/karl-johan-sj%C3%B6gren) who found the [related unit tests](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/tree/main/src/libraries/System.Formats.Asn1/tests). Based on these examples, I was able to write a comprehensive example program which parses an OCSP response.

```
using System.Formats.Asn1;

// An OCSP response according  https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6960#section-4.2.1 as Base64 encoded DER
string b64OCSPResponseDER = @"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";

byte[] ocspResponseDER = Convert.FromBase64String(b64OCSPResponseDER);

AsnReader asnReader1 = new(new ReadOnlyMemory<byte>(ocspResponseDER), AsnEncodingRules.DER);

AsnReader? ocspResponse = asnReader1.ReadSequence();

OCSPResponseStatus? responseStatus = ocspResponse?.ReadEnumeratedValue<OCSPResponseStatus>();

Asn1Tag context0 = new (TagClass.ContextSpecific, 0);

AsnReader? responseBytes = ocspResponse?.ReadSequence(context0);

AsnReader? _responseBytes = responseBytes?.ReadSequence();

string? responseType = _responseBytes?.ReadObjectIdentifier();

byte[]? response = _responseBytes?.ReadOctetString();

AsnReader asnReader2 = new(new ReadOnlyMemory<byte>(response), AsnEncodingRules.DER);

AsnReader? basicOCSPResponse = asnReader2.ReadSequence();

AsnReader? tbsResponseData = basicOCSPResponse?.ReadSequence();

// Skip parsing of tbsResponseData

AsnReader? signatureAlgorithm = basicOCSPResponse?.ReadSequence();

// Skip parsing of signatureAlgorithm

int unusedBitsCounter;
byte[]? signature = basicOCSPResponse?.ReadBitString(out unusedBitsCounter);

AsnReader? certs = basicOCSPResponse?.ReadSequence(context0);

AsnReader? cert1 = certs?.ReadSequence();

ReadOnlyMemory<byte> encodedValue = cert1.ReadEncodedValue();
string b64encodedCert1 = Convert.ToBase64String(encodedValue.ToArray());

bool endReached = !certs.HasData;

Console.WriteLine(b64encodedCert1);

enum OCSPResponseStatus : byte
{
    successful = 0, // Response has valid confirmations
    malformedRequest = 1, // Illegal confirmation request
    internalError = 2, // Internal error in issuer
    tryLater = 3, // Try again later
    // (4) is not used
    sigRequired = 5, // Must sign the request
    unauthorized = 6 //   --Request unauthorized
}
```